# android achartengine : show axes even if there is no plot data

Tags: android, achartengine

am trying to draw a line chart with achartengine in an Android App. The graph auto-refreshes every few seconds. The problem is : the axes become invisible if there is no data to plot. How do I make the axes appear even if there is nothing to plot?
Kindly help.

```
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset graphDataset = null;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer graphRenderer = null;
private GraphicalView graphView;

.....
.....

    this.graphDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    this.graphRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    this.graphRenderer.setXLabels(0);
...
/// other initialization code, like labels & fonts
...
// then i add the data to the series
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Simple graph");
            for (int i=0; i<valueArray.size();i++) {
                series.add(valueArray.get(i), yValue.get(i));
            }
    this.graphDataset.addSeries(series);
          ....
          // then I do renderer initialization
    XYSeriesRenderer xyRenderer = this.setChartLineProperties(index);
            ...
           // then finally initializing the graphview
    this.graphView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, this.graphDataset,
            this.graphRenderer);
```

Comment: Can you show what are u doing ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the axes to be displayed, the chart needs to know what values range it has to display. If there is no value added to the dataset, the range can be set this way:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(minX);
renderer.setXAxisMax(maxX);
renderer.setYAxisMin(minY);
renderer.setYAxisMax(maxY);
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan . I thought am setting these anyways. Let me check once more & get back! Thanks for your awesome work on the achartengine lib!

Comment: I am doing this already. Is there anything else am missing? Please help.

Comment: What values are you setting for minX, maxX, minY, maxY?

Comment: this is what am setting. They are fixed values ; so I guess that shouldn't be a problem. this.graphRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
   this.graphRenderer.setXAxisMax(14);
  this.graphRenderer.setYAxisMin(-100);
  this.graphRenderer.setYAxisMax(0);

Comment: and these are called as soon as the page is loaded, i.e. in onCreate() & onResume()